# Best way to create a max width for my website and test in a higher resolution?

Tags: html, css, resolution

I created a website that uses a lot of vh/vw sizing.  So the entire website re-sizes with the browser.  Is there any way to make the website stop re-sizing bigger at a certain point? My background images are sized for 1920 x 1080.  I want everything on the site to stop getting bigger when it reaches that point but most of the elements are sized like 80vw.  Also is there a way to test what my website will look like in a higher resolution?  My monitor is 1920 x 1080 and I don't have access to a higher res monitor.

Comment: Tried media queries?

Comment: for the higher resolution part : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400207/how-to-simulate-a-higher-resolution-screen and (if the website is online) this works: http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php