# Is there a way to simulate 4K resolution on my PC?

Tags: css

I am developing my website's design, and unfortunately I don't have a 4K monitor at the moment, but I want to see how will my website look at that resolution.

I am worrying because my website's background image has 2560 x 1600 resolution and CSS parameter `background-size: cover;`. I hope it won't have black background-color around the image, just because the image is smaller than 4K.

So is there any way to simulate a 4K resolution on PC?

Comment: `background-size: cover` doesn't care how big or small your image is. It will make sure the image always covers the entire background area.

Comment: What about temporarily replacing your image with one 960 x 600 px, and checking how it looks on a full hd monitor? That would basically be the same effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate a higher resolution screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400207/how-to-simulate-a-higher-resolution-screen)

Comment: Anyway, as @BoltClock has commented `background-size: cover` makes your image to take all available space of your HTML element, you can use zoom to test it. Use `Control +` or `Command +` in your browser

Comment: haha I want the exact opposite of this :-) Simulate full HD on my 4k screen

Answer (score 23):

You can use Mozilla Firefox to do the same.

Press Ctrl+Shift+M and firefox shall switch to 320 X 480 Resolution, Now you can edit the values in top and set it to 4096 X 2160 to emulate 4k resolution.

You will get both Horizontal and Vertical Scrolls

Below is the sample Screen for Same :-

[image]

Comment: That is very neat to know. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can test inside a VM with the VM set to have a higher res than your real screen:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/testing-application-on-various-screen-resolution-s/ba-p/316796

Comment: According to MS it is no longer supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/56801/remotefx-3d-adapter-no-longer-supported-how-are-mu.html and I can't add it with PS Add-VMRemoteFx3dVideoAdapter -VMName ("not supported" error). Are there any other similar options/replacements?